# Ikea Tradfri: Need to hit each remote twice

Tags: smart-home, ikea-tradfri

I've been using an Ikea Tradfri setup in my apartment for about a year. I've got lights, remotes, shortcuts buttons, outlets, blinds, a gateway and an extender. It's been working mostly smoothly.

A week ago something weird started happening. When I press on any of the buttons on the remotes or the shortcut buttons to turn some appliances on or off, at first they don't respond. I press again, and then they respond. (e.g. the light turns on.)

At first I shrugged it off, but then it started happening regularly on all my remotes and shortcut buttons. Clicking just once does nothing. After the first click, the second click does the trick. (These aren't two clicks rapidly in succession, there could be a few seconds between them.) Also, after the second click works, the button will work again with just one click. It feels as though the button was sleeping and I woke it up.

I haven't changed anything about my setup at all. I might think that the batteries on the remotes are dying out, but it would be quite the coincidence if they all ran out at the same time.

**Why this is happening and how can I fix it?**

(Note: I replaced all the batteries but the problem still happens.)

Comment: Try replacing the batteries in the remotes/buttons

Comment: I replaced all the batteries, the problem is still happening. Now it sometimes even takes 3-4 presses on the remote until it works.

Comment: Have you ruled out a physical cause (dirty/rusty contacts; first press "cleans" the contact a bit)? I've "fixed" any number of applications with electrical contact cleaner.

Comment: This problem started happening at roughly the same time on around 10 switches in different rooms. So dirty contacts seem unlikely.

Comment: Do you have new neighbours that moved in at the same time? Or anything else that may have introduced a new source of 2.4GHz interference? (And I assume you have rebooted the Tradfri gateway if you have one?)

Comment: I did reboot it. To me knowledge there aren't any new devices, but I don't want to ask my neighbors about that.